# Как присвоить стиль объекту, созданному в самом скрипте

Tags: javascript, изображения, border

```
var player = new Image();
player.src = "src/sprite.png";
```

Мне нужно сделать рамку вокруг моего изображения.
Попробовал сделать `player.border = 2;`, не сработало.

Comment: Надо использовать атрибут `style.border`, например, `player.style.border = '2px solid black'`

Answer (score 0):

В обычном JS все стили задаются через `.style` и потом само правило.

```js
var player = new Image();
player.src = "src/sprite.png";
player.style.border = "2px outset green";
```

Из серии **вредные, но простые советы могу предложить:**

```js
var stylize = "border: 2px solid green; border-radius: 25%; background: linear-gradient(to top, #b5bdc8 0%, #828c95 36%, #28343b 100%); color: white; text-align: center; height: 40px;";
document.getElementById("block").setAttribute("style", stylize);
```

```html
<div id="block">Alaala olololo</div>
```